# Woodford faucet leaking in wall

Tags: repair, faucet

I have a woodford frost free faucet that I just rebuilt
I will not leak unless we turn it on. What part of the rebuild did I do wrong.

Comment: You did that thing where you put the wrong thing in before you tightened down the  thingymabbobber.  **We can not tell you what you did wrong when we do not know what you did**. *Please add a detailed description of what you did and what model number hose bib it is*. Oh yes and welcome to DIY Stack. :)

Comment: So,, when you turn the valve off (close), it does not leak? Isn't that the point? Or is this a frost free that has a drip feature to it? If it is on (open) of course it will leak, you have allowed the water to escape the faucet.